# Singleton Inheritance Linker Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new with C++, and I got this linker error,

> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class DebugLog Singleton::instance" (?instance@?$Singleton@VDebugLog@@@@0VDebugLog@@A)

And here is the problematic codes:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
private:
    static T instance;
};

class DebugLog : public Singleton<DebugLog> {
public:
    void doNothing() {}
};

void main() {
    DebugLog::getInstance().doNothing();
}
```

Could anybody tell me how I can fix that linker error without losing the Singleton inheritance in DebugLog?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: You did not define the var, you just declared it.

Comment: ahh... something I don't know about template

Comment: Actually, that applies to normal non template singleton as well,In short it is not related to templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed:

```
template<typename T>
T Singleton<T>::instance;
```

Insert those lines after your class definition.

> In order to initialize a static data-member we must include a formal
>   definition outside the class, in the global scope.

For more information read [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) *(Section: Static members)*

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually define an instance of the `static` variable `DebugLog Singleton::instance` somewhere in your code, you just declared that it exists somewhere, but never actually created it to really exist. The linker is looking for it.

Here's [some](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/templates/static_members.html) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342550/static-member-initialization-for-specialized-template-class) of how to do it right.