# how to implement Singleton in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7750832/888051) is what I just read.

The way he implements Singleton in C++ confuses me. I got several Questions about it and here is his code:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& getInstance() {  //Question 1
        return instance;
    }
private:
    static T instance;
};

class DebugLog : public Singleton<DebugLog> {  //Question 2
public:
    void doNothing() {}
};
```

**Question**

1. I think we should put the `static T& getInstance()`'s definition outside of the class body, right?
2. He tries to make `class DebugLog` a singleton class, but when he inherits `Singleton<DebugLog>`, the `DebugLog` doesn't already exist, right? If right, then how can the template class `Singleton` instantiate an un-existent class?

Comment: 1 - you don't have to. 2 - [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It would certainly be cleaner if the function were defined outside of
   the class, and make the code easier to read and to maintain.  In this
   case, however, the complete class is small enough that the difference
   isn't very great, and of course, because we're dealing with a template,
   the actual definition still has to be included in every translation unit
   which uses it.

The C++ standard doesn't speak of “existence” with regards to classes (or anything
else).  At the point of template instantiation, name lookup finds
`DebugLog`, and finds that it is a class (thus, a type).  At that point,
it is an incomplete type, and there are only limited things you can do
with an incomplete type.  If the class template which is instantiated
doesn't do anything that requires a complete type (and `Singleton`
doesn't), then there is no problem.  (Note that only the class
definition is instantiated at this point; class member functions will
not be instantiated until they are used.)

I might add that there is still one important thing missing from the
code you posted: there is no definition for the declaration
`Singleton::instance`.  You still need to add a:

```
template<typename T> T Singleton<T>::instance;
```

somewhere.

Comment: yes, that's missing. Furthermore, in order to make the Singleton a real Singleton, I think we should make Singleton's ctor `Singleton<T>()` a protected/private member function, right?

Comment: @Alcott Since `Singleton<T>` is designed to be derived from, making its constructor `protected` would seem to be a good move.  One thing `Singleton<T>` can't do, and that needs doing, is to ensure that `DebugLog` has a private constructor, and that `Singleton<DebugLog>` is a friend, in order to use it.

Comment: that's right,:). Another thing is, when will the member function be instantiated in a template class?

Comment: @Alcott When it's "used".  For the standard's definition of "used"; a virtual function is considered "used" if any instance of an object of that type is constructed (because its address must be put in the `vtable`).  Otherwise, the function will only be instantiated if you actually call it, and the instantiation context will be that of where the function is called.  Similarly, a static member will only be instantiated if it is used; in this case, if (and when) you call `instance`.

Answer (score 5):

1) Nope, it doesn't matter how you structure your code. `Singleton` isn't a class, by the way: It's a *template*. Since the full template definition must be visitible at any instantiation site anyway, you might as well define everything inline.

2) `class DebugLog : public Singleton<DebugLog>` is fine. We are not inheriting from a non-existing class; rather, we are inheriting from the class `Singleton<DebugLog>`. Templates can be instantiated on incomplete types. (There are several rules what you can and cannot do with such a type parameter.)

For example, `template <typename T> class Foo { };` can certainly be instantiated on any type without problem. More interestingly, `template <typename T> struct PointerFactory { typedef T * type; };` can be instantiated on any type, complete or not. In the present situation, the purpose of the template parameter in the CRTP is solely to inform the base class of its eventual derived type, so this is entirely fine.

Comment: Does it mean, when a class is inheriting a template class, it doesn't matter what the template parameters are, right?

Comment: @Alcott: This hasn't really anything to do with inheritance. The only question is whether you can instantiate the template or not.

Answer (score -3):

You must use a pointer to T in this case:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& getInstance() {
        static T * instance = NULL;
        if (!instance)
            instance = new T;
        return *instance;
    }
};

class DebugLog : public Singleton<DebugLog> {  //Question 2
    public:
        void doNothing() {}
};
```

Comment: -1 Not only you do not "must" use static pointer instance you also do not destroy the object in your code.