# Error in Singleton

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I was implementing a singleton class for my game but every time I try to compile it, it gives a compilation error. The code is as follows :

```
    //Singleton.h
    #pragma once

    class Singleton{
    public:
        static Singleton* Instance();

    private:
        Singleton(){};

        static Singleton* m_instance;
    };

    Singleton* SingletonInstance = Singleton::Instance();
```

Singleton.cpp

```
//Singleton.cpp
#include "Untitled1.h"

Singleton* m_instance = nullptr;


Singleton* Singleton::Instance(){
    if(m_instance == nullptr){
        m_instance = new Singleton;
    }
    return m_instance;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in df (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\Untitled1.o||In function `ZN9Singleton8InstanceEv':|
C:\Users\Samsung R519\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp|7|multiple definition of `SingletonInstance'|
obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\Samsung R519\Desktop\main.cpp|4|first defined here|
obj\Debug\Untitled1.o:Untitled1.cpp|| undefined reference to `Singleton::m_instance'|
obj\Debug\Untitled1.o:Untitled1.cpp|| undefined reference to `Singleton::m_instance'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 10 second(s)) ===|
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reconsider (a) why you need a singleton: it’s almost always an anti-pattern; and (b) why you are using pointers here. Using a simple object with automatic storage and return it by reference is almost certainly superior, unless you need deferred initialisation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singleton Inheritance Linker Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750832/singleton-inheritance-linker-error)

Comment: Another (better?) way to implement a singleton in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3052438

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. `Singleton* SingletonInstance = Singleton::Instance();` You shouldn't put the definition in header file. Instead, you should declare `SingletonInstance` in the header and define it in .cpp file. In fact, there's no need to have this global variable. You can always call `Singleton::Instance()` to get the singleton.
2. `m_instance` is a member of `Singleton`, so you should define it with the class name: `Singleton::m_instance`

The solution:

```
// xxx.h
// other code...
extern Singleton* SingletonInstance; // declaration

// xxx.cpp
// other code...
Singleton* Singleton::m_instance = nullptr;   // specify the class name

Singleton* SingletonInstance = Singleton::Instance(); // definition
```

Answer (score 3):

In the .cpp file you are defining a new `m_instance` that is not a member.

Please try

```
Singleton* Singleton::m_instance = nullptr;
```

Comment: It worked but now this error is coming:                            Singleton.cpp|7|multiple definition of `SingletonInstance'

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Singleton{
           ....
           static Singleton* m_instance;
  }
```

and

```
Singleton* m_instance = nullptr;
```

Even though have the same name, they are different pointers because they have different scopes: the first one is a declaration of a class member and the second one is both a declaration and a definition of a pointer in the global namespace.

So, what you are looking for is the definition of the class member pointer, which is:

```
Singleton* Singleton::m_instance = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the Scott Meyers singleton. I will avoid any error related to order of initialisation and any memory management error related to the singleton.

Here's how you implement it:

```
struct Singleton {
    static Singleton& instance() {
        static Singleton myInstance;

        return myInstance;
    }
};
```

If you want to return a pointer instead of a reference, this is equally fine.