# Static variable in template undefined

Tags: c++

Why isn't this code working and giving an "undefined max" ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  static T const max;
};

template<> struct Foo<int> { // Specialization
    static int max; 
};

template<typename T> T const Foo<T>::max = 22;

template struct Foo<int>;

int main() {

    struct Foo<int> ma;
    cout << ma.max;

    return 0;
}
```

I defined the static variable and I instantiated the template (I believe the explicit instantiation is useless here).

What's wrong?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342550/static-member-initialization-for-specialized-template-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template<typename T> T const Foo<T>::max = 22;` is the definition of the general case, not for the specialization.

You have also to define `int Foo<int>::max = 22;` for the int specialization.

Comment: why can't the definition for the general case be used?

Comment: @user129506 Because an explicit specialisation of a class template is a separate class totally unrelated to the primary template - it can have entirely different members, for example.