# Custom enum template class

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to write my own enum class to extend the features of the default enum classes a little bit - like explicit conversions to strings, iterating over the enum, etc. Since I didn't know where to start I asked the mighty Google and found [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/when-enum-just-isnt-enough-enumeration-c/184403955?pgno=1) (fairly old) blog post. I adapted the class to my needs and fixed some compiler issues and came up with the following template

```
template < typename T >
class Enum {    
private:
    int m_iValue;
    const char* m_sName;

    // comparator for the set
    struct EnumPtrLess {
        bool operator() (const Enum<T>* lhs, const Enum<T>* rhs) {
            return lhs->m_iValue < rhs->m_iValue;
        }
    };

protected:
    static std::set<const Enum<T>*, EnumPtrLess> m_sInstances;

    explicit Enum(int iVal, const char* sName) 
        : m_iValue(iVal)
        , m_sName(sName)
    {
        m_sInstances.insert(this); // store the object inside the container
    }

public:
    typedef std::set<const Enum<T>*, EnumPtrLess> instance_list;
    typedef typename instance_list::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef typename instance_list::size_type size_type;
    // convenient conversion operators
    operator int() const { return m_iValue; }
    explicit operator std::string() const { return m_sName; }

    static const Enum<T>* FromInt(int iValue) 
    {
        const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_sInstances.begin(), m_sInstances.end(), 
            [&](const Enum<T>* e) { return e->m_iValue == iValue; } );
        return (it == m_sInstances.end() ? NULL : *it);
    }

    static size_type Size() { return m_sInstances.size(); }

    static const_iterator begin() { return m_sInstances.begin(); }
    static const_iterator end() { return m_sInstances.end(); }

};
```

The problem I have appears when I try to use it. Since `m_sInstances` is a static member it needs to be instantiated outside of the template like shown below:

```
class EDirection : public Enum<EDirection> {
private:
    explicit EDirection(int iVal, const char* sName) 
        : Enum<EDirection>(iVal, sName)
    {}
public:
    static const EDirection NORTH;
};

template <> Enum<EDirection>::instance_list Enum<EDirection>::m_sInstances;

const EDirection EDirection::NORTH(1, "NORTH");
```

The specialization of `m_sInstances` screws up the linking and let's the build fail:

> undefined reference to `Enum::m_sInstances'

Is there any way to avoid that? I can't think of any solution.

Comment: You need to initialise the member to instantiate it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342550/static-member-initialization-for-specialized-template-class

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a specialisation though. It looks like you could just use an ordinary template static member initialisation.  
`template <typename T> typename Enum<T>::instance_list Enum<T>::m_sInstances{};`

Comment: @Mic This is what I ended up doing ;-)